# Get result Bounding Boxes of Spatial Indexing

Tags: postgis, postgresql

When I create a Spatial Index in PostGIS, the result looks something like this: https://image.slidesharecdn.com/mongodcknize-120711124945-phpapp01/95/rtree-spatial-indexing-with-mongodb-mongodc-14-728.jpg?cb=1342011093

Is is possible to retrieve the bounding boxes, with information to which polygon they belong? I am trying to create a "pseudo spatial" index for a database, that has no spatial option. I try to implent an efficient "point in polygon" query, where it first queries the bounding boxes and then the respective polygons.

Comment: How are you planning to 'implement' said index? If not by providing a solid in-memory data structure as a core extension to your DB system, I'd rather use whatever range index your DB has available and index both the x&y min max values of the polygons.

Comment: @geozelot I like that idea!